# How to transfer entire directory from one server to another via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two servers, access to SSH on both. I want to transfer entire directory from server A to server B. 
They are both remote servers to me.

Am I right to assume it is possible to log into SSH terminal on my local PC, connect to server A, and do some magical command that will initiate a transfer between the two servers while being able to log out of terminal on my own local machine?

Comment: Please search for `rsync` and `scp` - this question has been answered thousands of time on all kind of sites.

Answer (score 21):

On server A:

```
$ scp -r /path/to/directory someuser@serverB:/path/to/files/.
```

The above command will copy the files from serverA to serverB using someuser (a user on serverB). The directory (`/path/to/directory`) will be copied as a directory to the directory on serverB into the directory `/path/to/files/`.

Comment: And if you want to log out before the transfer is finished, look into the "screen" command - you can start a screen, start the scp (or rsync) command, and then detach (ctrl+a, ctrl+d) and log out, while everything keeps running remotely inside the screen session.

Comment: How do you provide the password in the same command so that entering from prompt won't be needed.

Comment: @C.Gabriel - you shouldn't be passing a password to `scp`. Instead you can use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your public SSH key to the remote server, `serverB`, and then going forward `scp` will not need to prompt for any password, it'll use the SSH key to auth. See here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453679/how-to-properly-copy-private-keys-from-remote-servers-to-my-localmachine-so-i-ca/453680#453680.